# Converting image corner coordinates to world coordinates

Tags: python, pyvista

I am attempting to create a world file that accompanies each screenshot I produce so that I can easily reference the files in CAD in the correct location, orientation, and scale as my original input data.

The issue is that I need to obtain the coordinates of the upper left corner of the exported image to use as the base point in the worldfile.

If we use the simple code below you will see the the top left corner of the rendered polydata is `(0, 1)`. However I need the actual coordinates of the corner of the image.

I had assumed that the [`plotter.bounds()`](https://docs.pyvista.org/version/stable/api/plotting/_autosummary/pyvista.Plotter.bounds.html) would return the polydata bounds and the [`renderer.bounds()`](https://docs.pyvista.org/version/stable/api/plotting/_autosummary/pyvista.Renderer.bounds.html) would return the image bounds. However they both return the polydata bounds. Any ideas?

```
import pyvista as pv
points = [[0, 0, 0],

          [1, 0, 0],

          [0.5, 1.0, 0]]
mesh = pv.PolyData(points)
pl = pv.Plotter()
pl.add_mesh(mesh)
pl.show_bounds(location='all', all_edges=True, grid=True)
pl.camera.tight(padding=0.1)
pl.parallel_projection = True #redunant but set he to remove perspective questions
pl.screenshot('with_padding')
pl.show()
```

[image: screenshot with a grid and three points, with some border between the edge of the grid and the edge of the image]

`pl.bounds`
(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

`pl.renderer.bounds`
(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

Does anyone know of a method that returns the image corner coordinates?

Comment: I don't think your question is well-defined in the general case. A single point in the plotter window corresponds to infinitely many points along the view axis. Do I take it correctly from your example data and screenshot that you always have an `xy` view (i.e. view from the top), and you always only need the `x` and `y` coordinates (`z` being arbitrary)?

Comment: You are correct....always in xy and always the true image corner coordinate.  The purpose of the basic image was to show that 0,1 is the xy of the polydata but it is not the x,y corner of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I noted in a comment that the question can only be answered if we restrict ourselves the an `xy` view (because in that case the `z` coordinate is arbitrary but you only seem to be looking for `x` and `y` coordinates), it seems that VTK readily has machinery that can do these coordinate transformations via [`vtkCoordinate()`](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCoordinate.html#details).

You can create a `vtkCoordinate` instance, set its coordinate system to be normalized viewport, use the corresponding normalized coordinates (`(0, 0)` is bottom left corner, `(1, 1)` is upper right), then query the corresponding world points using the plotter's renderer:

```py
import pyvista as pv
from vtkmodules.vtkRenderingCore import vtkCoordinate

# example data
points = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0.5, 1.0, 0],
]
mesh = pv.PolyData(points)

# example plot
pl = pv.Plotter()
pl.add_mesh(mesh)
pl.show_bounds(location='all', all_edges=True, grid=True)
pl.camera.tight(padding=0.1)
pl.parallel_projection = True

# get world coordinates of upper left corner of viewport
coordinate = vtkCoordinate()
coordinate.SetCoordinateSystemToNormalizedViewport()
coordinate.SetValue(0, 1)  # (0, 0) is lower left, (1, 1) is upper right
coords = coordinate.GetComputedWorldValue(pl.renderer)
print(coords)
# (-0.050000000000000044, 1.05, 0.06472500000000003)
```

I slightly edited your example data, and the last code block prints the world coordinates of the upper left corner. Notice you have a nonzero `z` coordinate; you'll have to make sure to discard this, or check how this behaves with a real, thick mesh. If you have older `vtk` and you get an import error, you can use `from vtk import vtkCoordinate` instead of the `vtkmodules` import, but this will be a lot slower (pyvista uses `vtkCoordinate` internally, so the above version of the import is free).

Looking at your original figure, `(-0.05, 1.05)` looks correct to me. Unfortunately I couldn't visually prove that this is the correct position, because adding a new mesh even with `reset_camera=False` messes with the resulting view, even if I restore `pl.camera_position` from before the second mesh is added. I suspect this has to do with something related to `pl.camera.tight()`. Anyway, you should be able to confirm the values with your real mesh.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is just what I was looking for...I will confirm the coordinates but I suspect this to be correct.